# Django Web App Integration with Salesforce via Heroku Connect

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, salesforce

I'm working on integrating Salesforce with my Django web app via Heroku Connect. I'm using Postgres for my database. I've set up Heroku Connect so that my Salesforce tables are replicating to Postgres correctly:

[image: Postgres schemas]

However, I'm not sure how to access the "salesforce" schema in code. (E.g. in views.py file). I've taken a look at [this tutorial](https://www.amvtek.com/blog/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/) to set up my settings.py file but I'm still unsure of the syntax needed to access and update the "salesforce" schema in code. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

After updating my settings.py file according to the linked tutorial in the question, I've decided to use raw queries to access the Salesforce database directly in Python. The Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/) is good. For example:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  cursor.execute("UPDATE salesforce.account SET name = %s WHERE sfid = %s",[newName, id])
```